# Change an image using triggers getting System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension error

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I have written this code:

```
<Image>
   <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" Value="Play">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="bin\debug\Tasto Play.jpeg"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" Value="Pause">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="bin\debug\Tasto Pause.jpeg"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

But when I run the debug an error comes out. The error is System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension.

MyProperty is string.

Can someone help me?

Thanks, 
Jacopo.

Comment: The type of `MyProperty` is?

Comment: What do your bindings look like?

Comment: Is that the full error message? Im sure there must be more... please post the full error

Comment: I guess "bin\debug\" is not a valid path during runtime. Just use the file names without relative path when the image files are located in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: The type of MyProperty is string.

Comment: The full Error is this:
'An exception has been produced during the specification of a value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension.'' I number line '58' and position rules '30.'

Comment: Clemens, I tried to run the project without "bin\debug\" but the program said that the file doesn't exist even if the executable is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe is the `MyProperty` property type: if it is string, there is not problem, but if it is, an enum for instance, you must set the type:

```
 <Image>
   <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" Value="{x:Type namespace:EnumType.Play}">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="bin\debug\Tasto Play.jpeg"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" Value="{x:Type namespace:EnumType.Pause">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="bin\debug\Tasto Pause.jpeg"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Maybe could be the setter property, source (I think) is of type Uri, maybe you are not formatting well the string, maybe you must use an absulute uri (for test), but I think it is not a well formatted string path, so the Xaml's converter couldn'd create correctly the Uri type.

Hope this could helps, or give you some idea.

Comment: Thanks Raul.
I think the same thing but I don't succeed in finding a code that allow me to get the Path in Uri type. I think that there is at least a way to change images in a Button.Content using triggers.

Comment: Try using a path like this: "../YouProjectImageFolder/some_image.png", and then include your image in the project, and set in the properties BuildActio = Resource.

Comment: I don't understand, the image is saved in the debug folder, where should I save it?

Comment: If the image is created or loaded in RUN-time, then you must use a relative root to the application, you do not have to write bin\debug. But if you image is added at the project in design time, then you must add to the project (in some image folder) then right click-property and then set BuildAction=Resource and Copy To Output Directory = Never, the you may access the images in design time, with out copy it to the out put folder, the image are embeded in the application excecutable. Then you may use the route like abouve...

Comment: Thanks Raul.
I have implemented the images as resources in the debug folder and now the program runs.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For add an image as a resource in a project you have to click "Project" in the "Visual Studio Menu Bar" and click "properties of the project".
Then a window with various toolbars (like internet) will open in your screen.
Choose the "resources toolbar"
(view the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjC0w.jpg)
and click the arrow near the "Add Resources" button that will be on the top of the window.
Click "Add existing file" and choose the file.
Then you go in the "Explore solution window" and open the "Debug folder" that will have the new resources.
Click with "the right button of mouse" on the new resources that you have added
and click on "Properties".
On the left of your screen will appear a "Properties window".
(view the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqIc1.jpg)

You have to choose on "Compilating operations" the "Resources" item.
Now you can use your image as a resources in wpf.

I hope that this could helps.
Jacopo